# ¿Como recorrer un append que se encuentra dentro de un for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

En `HTML` tengo lo sgte:

```
    <div class="row"> 
      <ul class="simplefilter">
         Simple filter controls:
           <li class="active" data-filter="all">All</li>

      </ul>
    </div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="filtr-container">

   </div>
</div>
```

y en un archivo `JS`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {

        $(".simplefilter").append("<li class='d' data-filter='"+[i]+"'>Cityscape</li>"); // ESTE FUNCIONA BIEN

        $(".filtr-container").append("<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item' data-category='"+[i]+"' data-sort='Busy streets'><img class='img-responsive' src='img/city_1.jpg' alt='sample image'><span class='item-desc'>Busy Streets</span></div>");
    };
```

la clase `simplefilter` se esta recorriendo 5 veces como lo indica el for y funciona a la perfeccion pero la clase `filtr-container` no me esta 'tomando' el metodo `append` y si uso el metodo `html` solo lo recorre una vez.

Aque se debe esto, si de igual manera estoy recorriendo `[i]` dentro de `data-category='"+[i]+"'`?

el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
jquery.filterizr.js:414 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at n.fn.init._makeSubarrays (jquery.filterizr.js:414)
    at Object.init (jquery.filterizr.js:159)
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.filterizr (jquery.filterizr.js:84)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (david:92)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el HTML completo para ver dónde puede estar el error?

Comment: Listo ya puse el html

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema, debe estar relacionado con otra cosa que no nos muestras porque tanto a @Asier como a mí nos funciona correctamente (he borrado mi respuesta mientras me proporcionas más datos).

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, al parecer el problema esta es en una libreria que he descargado, la cual esta trabajando de una manera no muy comoda, gracias por tu interes.

Comment: Si usas angular debes hacerlo de otra forma. Si nos dices cuál es la otra librería te podremos ayudar a adaptar tu código a ella.

Comment: estoy usando jquery normalmente pero el plus o bien, la libreria que me hace dinamico el  html y que me esta arrojando los errores es esta jquery.filterizr.js (cabe mencionar, que no estoy manipulando este js)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59137/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-jdavid).

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 414 de tu script? ¿Sobre que objeto estás llamando a push? ¿No estará mal asignado ese objeto?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo las dos sentencias se ejecutan en el bucle.
El problema lo tendrás en otra parte del código.

Mira tu ejemplo funcionando:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {

        $(".simplefilter").append("<li class='d' data-filter='"+[i]+"'>Cityscape</li>"); // ESTE FUNCIONA BIEN

        $(".filtr-container").append("<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 filtr-item' data-category='"+[i]+"' data-sort='Busy streets'><img class='img-responsive' src='img/city_1.jpg' alt='sample image'><span class='item-desc'>Busy Streets</span></div>");
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"> 
  <ul class="simplefilter">
     Simple filter controls:
     <li class="active" data-filter="all">All</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="filtr-container">

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Asier Villanueva, gracias por tu interes, pff vaya, que raro quizas debe de ser problemas con la libreria que estoy usando, ps el ejemplo es funcional y lo he probado aparte y funciona, de igualmanera gracias por tu aporte.